# What is default size of String constant pool in Java?

Tags: java

I want to understand is there any default size given to string constant pool?

Is there any variation in string constant pool in different version on java? 
What is default size of String constant pool?

Comment: Are you asking about the [`intern()` pool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--) or the [class file constant pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4)?

Comment: Why? The question has no meaning. The string constant pool is large enough to hold all the constant String literals that occur in classes loaded. The point of knowing the size also escapes me.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://java-performance.info/string-intern-in-java-6-7-8/) article, String Constant pool size varies across different Java versions and releases (but the article itself is over 3 years old, so some changes on the newest Java releases might have been made since then).

The String Pool is implemented as a HashMap. So,

1. Up until **Java 6**, the default Pool size is 1009 entries and is limited by PermGen size, which became configurable in Java6u30 release.
2. In **Java 7** the default hash table size was increased up to 60013 entries and is still configurable with flag `-XX:StringTableSize=<value>`.
3. In **Java 8** PermGen area was removed and constant pool was moved into heap, making its size limited only by the program's memory limit (and it still accepts the table size option).

Comment: The string pool was moved out of the PemGen in Java 7, and in Java 8.

Comment: [*JEP 122: Remove the Permanent Generation*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/122)

Answer (score 0):

In most of JVM default size of Perm Space is around "64MB".